# Wp метод ввода gmap input

Tags: google-maps-api, php, wordpress

здравствуйте, пишу плагин к gravityforms на wp. мой вопрос - как вывести google map, дать возможность пользователю помещать на карту маркер, ну и соответственно прочитать его ширину и долготу. есть ли какой то устоявшийся механизм для реализации этого? знаю что карту можно вывести через айфрэм или через яваскрипт. кто в курсе как это правильно делается?

Answer (score 1):

Отличная [статья для старта](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110460/). Не смотрите, что на сервере используется asp.net, там все по сути тривиально. Вас должна интересовать клиентская часть, т.е. Javascript. Там же можно посмотреть и потыкать [пример](http://cocosanka.ru/map).
Ну и конечно [примеры от гугла](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple_v3) как работают их карты очень наглядны.